# How to reformat tabs in vimoutliner?

Tags: vim, tabs, macvim, outline

I am trying to standardize on Vimoutliner to define IT projects.  The plugin has capacity for multiple levels of headings, which are indented using the appropriate number of tab characters.

Each tab character is represented by '>...' (one for each level of heading below the top).

Paragraphs under a heading inherit the space of the heading's indent, and are prefixed with a ':'

I would like to change the VISIBLE representation of the tabs to a series of blank spaces, with the end of the series culminating with a '|' (pipe).  So a third tier heading which noe looks like

```
>...>...>...
```

would now look like

```
           |
```

Note that I do not want to CHANGE the lines after the fact, but, rather, to affect the original appearance of the tab character.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with conceal if your vim is compiled with +conceal (you can check to see if `:echo has("conceal")` returns 1). First you need to put

```
set conceallevel=1
```

in your ~/.vimrc. Then you can do:

```
syntax match Entity ">..." conceal
```

Also see `:help hl-Conceal` and `:help concealcursor`.